# jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).mark is not a function TypeError: $(...).mark is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>View and Filter Submittals</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <script src="assets/js/uikit.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/js/tokenvalidate.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/mark.js/dist/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/mark.js/dist/mark.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/viewstyle.css">
<!-- Back to top -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--My code jquery code url for collapse -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/vmenuModule.css" />
<!--Ends here jquery code url for collapse -->
<link href="assets/css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <script src="globalsearch/search_set.js"></script>
    <script src="globalsearch/search_content.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="globalsearch/search.css">
    <script src="globalsearch/search.js"></script>
    <!-- Responsivness and Load -->
<script src="src/js/custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/viewstyle.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/footer.css"> 
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="modal/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="modal/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="modal/assets/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="modal/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Bootstrap Modal Login Popup Form // -->
<script src="modal/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="modal/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="modal/assets/js/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="modal/assets/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

> As i need to clear the console for my project.i'm getting this error in console. but mark.js functionality is working as expected. i have kept the jquery at the top before mark.js still throwing error.

Comment: I do not seen any `mark.js`. Where you have loaded `mark.js`

Comment: @Sinto i'm sorry for the mistake.now added correct file

Comment: check the path calling `mark.js` & `jquery.js` & try by calling `mark.js` at the very last.

Comment: You haven't embedded mark.js correctly, like mentioned above. It requires jQuery to be embedded first (in the jQuery version at least).

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.